# Drawing a line at a fixed angle relative to data with Chart.js

Tags: geometry, chart.js, trigonometry

I am using `Chart.js` to map an aircraft's vertical approach path:

[image]

The code to get the actual approach path is relatively straightforward:

```
   var position_reports = [
      {
         altitude: 4606
         heading: 42.94507920742035
         latitude: 35.16972222222222
         longitude: -101.75638888888889
         speed: 133
         vertical_speed: -714},
      }, 
      // additional position reports redacted for clarity
   ];

   var data = [];

   for(var x = 0; x < position_reports.length; x++) {
      data.push(position_reports[x].altitude);
   }

    // at this point, data looks like this: [4606, 4605, 4604, 4603, 4603, 4602, etc....]

    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Actual Altitude',
                    borderColor: '#ff6600',
                    data: data,
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    fill: false,
                }
            ]
        },
       // additional options redacted for clarity
    });
```

This above aircraft's glidepath (mostly) follows a standard 3-degree descent path. I would like to draw a  fixed 4-degree and 2-degree line so I can make sure the aircraft's actual vertical path falls between 4 and 2 degrees. Hand drawn (and thus not to scale) example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

How to I go about adding these red lines into `Chart.js`, relative to the vertical path? Is it possible with this library, or should I be using something else? Any feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a custom plugin to do it, but I think this plugin of chart.js itself can help you out looking at the example. If you specify the right start and end it should draw a straight line.
https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation#line-annotations